# Changing the input's text color depending on it's value, Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular7

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4">What is the capital city of Italy?
  </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="first_question" #first_question />
</div>
```

So, I want to make the input color to be red, unless the user inputs the correct answer which is rome? Any ideas? i tried this but it didnt work:

```
placeholder="Type" [style.color]="Type === 'rome' ? 'red' : 'green'"
```

Comment: Show the TS Code

Comment: placeholder="Type" [style.red]="Type === 'rome'" [style.green]="Type !== 'rome'" is a one of simple way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to declare a variable in TS.

```
TheCapitalOfItaly:string = '';
```

then, in HTML:

```
[(ngModel)]=="TheCapitalOfItaly" [style.color]="TheCapitalOfItaly === 'rome' ? 'green': 'red'"
```

Comment: the input is on test.component.html so I have to put the declared variable in the test.component.ts, right?

Comment: Yes, and of course make sure that " test.component.html" is registered in "test.component.ts" URLS

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [`Reactive Forms`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) then use:

```
this.your_formgroup.get('first_question').value
```

So the HTML Code will be:

```
<div [formGroup]="your_formgroup">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Input" formControlName="first_question" [style.color]="this.your_formgroup.get('first_question').value === 'rome' ? 'red' : 'green'">
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

> Without FormGroup:

- Removed `formControlName`
- Have used `.toLowerCase()` because `Rome` and `rOmE` is valid inputs:)

HTML Code:

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Input" [(ngModel)]="first_question" [style.color]="first_question.toLowerCase() === 'rome' ? 'red' : 'green'">
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
first_question: any = "";
```

[`WORKING_DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tesj8a-vmkegi)